# Ubercart with Panels

Tags: panels, ubercart

I would like to know if anyone is experienced with ubercart with panels.
I am making a website with these two modules, the ubercart is for the online store, the panels is for the layout. And the site headers and footers are within the mini panels of the panels module.

I would like to make the mini panels also appear on the ubercart checkout, cart pages but i dont know if it is possible, since the checkout , cart pages are generated by the ubercart modules and they are not nodes, views, and seems it is not possible to assign them info mini panels in panel module.

Is there any way to make a page generated by module appear as mini panels, and so that i can create a new page by using the mini panels. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Context module to conditionally show blocks in certain regions.

So, in your case, you can create a context that is activated on the /cart and /cart/checkout paths, and add the minipanels blocks that you want to the header and footer.